# Xcode crashes immediately after opening

Tags: xcode

When I tried to open any project Xcode crashes immediately, like in 0.5 seconds after clicking on the project file of Xcode,

When I again try to open it, it shows the following box,

[image]

and after some time it shows a box of "Problem Details and System Configuration".
I add that screenshot here,

[image]

Comment: My question is how to open Xcode again perfectly, I click on Don't Reopen but it not work for me, Xcode crashes again and again, what to do now???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I got the solution of the problem, just click on the "Don't Reopen" button and then open the Xcode project after some time like 30 to 40 Second, your Xcode project opens successfully and perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue Sanket Khatri.  This may not be the best solution but is a good workaround until a better one is found.  I was able to solve this by going to my (name).xcworkspace file then right-clicking and clicking "show packaged content."  Then after that move-out or delete the "xcuserdata."  This is a solution whether it is the best or not I am not sure but it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you 117MAsterChief96 for your support but after some time Xcode starts automatically and sometimes this problem occurs again but then when I reopen the Xcode project and all went well.

Your solution also works sometimes when some projects don't open even if I reopen them, so Thank you very much for your support and help.